# Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_avx2.so or libmkl_def.so in R

Tags: r

I wrote a R package with Rcpp and RcppArmadillo and load it into a supercomputer cluster running on Unix. However, it produces the above error while I try to run one of the function in a R instance on the cluster. Does anyone know how to solve this? Module loaded on the cluster is R-3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the particulars of your HPC system but on "vanilla" machines it is easy to use MKL ... because, as frequently stated before, BLAS and LAPACK are *an interface* to which MKL adheres.

See for example the blog posts I wrote here about using MKL on Ubuntu

- http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2018/06/24#019_mkl_soon_in_debian
- http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2018/04/15#018_mkl_for_debian_ubuntu

and the GitHub repo with the script they reference

- https://github.com/eddelbuettel/mkl4deb

So if I had to guess I'd say that your dynamic linker part only sees parts of the MKL library directory.  And for what it is worth, I have had from other users on large research systems.  Good luck!

Comment: I am only starting to learn Linux and Unix so most of the stuff you mentioned kind of flew over my head. But it's still much appreciated. However, I loaded a newer version of R.3.6.0 instance on the HPC cluster and now everything works. What does this mean?